# Bringing a virtual Torah in the bathroom?

Tags: halacha, bathroom

Knowing the issur of bringing a Sefer into a tamei place, can I bring a virtual Sefer into the bathroom? (I.e a phone with a davening app on it) would it matter if the app was open or closed? If the phone was on or off? Would a screen protector change the Halacha? Sources please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**
according to [Rustybrick](https://www.rustybrick.com/jewish-iphone-siddur-bathroom.html) (maker of many Torah/Jewish apps) one **is allowed** to bring their iPhone/iPod touch into a restroom, just be careful not to read any of the content while there.

> (1) What is the Halachic status of the Siddur when the device is NOT displaying the text?
>
> (2) Even when the text IS visible, is that different than a printed text in a book?
>
> To answer the 2nd question first: Although a text displayed on a LED
> screen is not considered a Halachic text (i.e. one may not use such a
> text for a mezuzah- sorry iPad Torah) - it is not appropriate for one
> to have the text displayed in a restroom, for it may cause him to
> think about or say what he is reading, which is also prohibited in an
> unclean place.
>
> Concerning the 1st issue, **since the text on the iPhone is stored
> internally on flash memory drive, it’s not considered a Halachic
> writing at all**. At best, is electronically charged ones and zeros
> which has no sacred status whatsoever. So, to answer our original
> question – You may bring your iPhone/iPod touch into a restroom, just
> be careful not to read any of the content while there.

Being as this is their business, I'm sure they've done lots of research into this topic, and even have a "contact us" on their website where can get the exact sources they use for the ruling:

> For sources and further discussion, please feel free to [contact us](https://www.rustybrick.com/company_contact.php).

---

I actually emailed them and will update when they respond, but until then- here are 2 gedolim quoted in blogposts who suggest that digital writing is not writing:

**Maran Rabbeinu Ovadia Yosef zt”l**- quoted in [this article](http://halachayomit.co.il/en/default.aspx?HalachaID=1829)

**R' Shlomo Zalman Auerbach zt”l**- "Shooting electrons is not considered by the Torah as writing" cited in [this article](https://www.rabbibelovski.co.uk/2008/01/so-can-you-write-gods-name-on-computer.html)